# Como manter os dados na tela ao clicar no botão voltar com Angular 8

Tags: angular-8

estou estudando angular ao implementar uma pequena aplicação de questionários me deparei com o seguinte problema. ao clicar no botão voltar, observei que as minhas opções selecionadas sumiam, existe alguma forma de manter essas escolhas salvas na tela ate que eu salve o questionário??

meu HTML

```
    <div class="content">
        <span class="etapas">Etapa 3 de 4</span>
        <h2>{{pergunta?.dsPergunta}}</h2>
        <p>Escolha até 3 opções</p>
        <div class="box-questoes">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let res of pergunta.respostas" (click)="insereResposta(res.cdResposta)"
                        [ngClass]="respostas?.includes(res.cdResposta) ? 'active' : ''">
                    <p>{{res.dsResposta}}</p>
                    <small>{{res.dsAssunto}}</small>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button (click)="addPergunta()" [routerLink]="[ '/comentario']" class="btn-basico" [disabled]="respostas?.length === 0">Continuar</button>
        <a href="#" (click)="limpaRespostas()" [routerLink]="[ '/forma', cdPergunta, avaliacao]" class="link-bottom">Voltar</a>
    </div>
</div>
<ngx-ui-loader></ngx-ui-loader>
```

meu TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { PesquisaService } from 'src/app/services/pesquisa.service';
import { Pergunta } from 'src/app/models/pergunta';
import { Resposta } from 'src/app/models/resposta';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-questoes',
  templateUrl: './questoes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questoes.component.scss']
})
export class QuestoesComponent implements OnInit {

  avaliacao: number;
  questoes: Resposta[];
  selecionado = false;
  pergunta: Pergunta;
  respostas: number[];

  cdPergunta: number;
  formaResposta: number;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private pesquisaService: PesquisaService) {
    this.respostas = [];
    this.avaliacao = parseInt( this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('avaliacao'));
    this.formaResposta = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('formaResposta'), 10);

  }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.pesquisaService.getPerguntaResposta(3).subscribe(perguntaResponse => {
        this.pergunta = perguntaResponse;

        if(this.formaResposta == 14){
         this.pergunta.respostas = this.pergunta.respostas.filter(a => a.cdResposta != 12);
        }

        if(this.avaliacao <= 2){
          this.pergunta.dsPergunta = "O que MENOS você gosta?";
        }if(this.avaliacao >= 4){
          this.pergunta.dsPergunta = "O que MAIS você gosta?";

        }
      });
  }

  insereResposta(cdResposta: number) {
    if (this.respostas.includes(cdResposta)) {
      this.respostas.splice(this.respostas.indexOf(cdResposta), 1);
    } else if (this.respostas.length < 3) {
      this.respostas.push(cdResposta);
    }
    console.log(this.respostas);
  }

  addPergunta() {
    this.pesquisaService.addPergunta(this.pergunta.cdPergunta, this.respostas);
  }

  limpaRespostas() {
    this.pesquisaService.limpaRespostas();
  }

}
```

Comment: nao sei se seria a melhor solução, mas pensou em armazenar o que precisa no localStorage do navegador ou ate mesmo criar um singleton e armazenar os itens que precisa? e entao quando entrar na tela que quer novamente, verificar se existe itens armazenados no localStorage ou singleton, como preferir fazer

Comment: o que seria o local storage?

Answer (score 1):

O `localStorage` é um tipo de armazenamento local do navegador, nele você armazena itens em chave-valor.

Temos alguns métodos:

1. setItem: definir valor para uma chave no seu armazenamento local

`window.localStorage.setItem(chave, valor)`

`window.localStorage.setItem("nome", "Alexsandro")`

2. getItem: recuperar o valor definido anteriormente

`window.localStorage.getItem(chave)`

`window.localStorage.getItem("nome") // retorna "Alexsandro"`

3. removeItem: remover o valor definido anteriormente

`window.localStorage.removeItem(chave)`

`window.localStorage.removeItem("nome")`

4. clear: limpar os itens existentes no armazenamento

`window.localStorage.clear()`

---

Você poderia fazer algo como:

```
const formulario = {
       nome: "Alexsandro",
       email: "alexsandro@exemplo.com"
    };
    
window.localStorage.setItem("formulario", JSON.stringify(formulario));
var retorno = window.localStorage.getItem("formulario");
console.log(retorno);
```

Criei um exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leohenr95/eqkzdcLp/5/).

Para visualizar, se estiver usando o Google Chrome:

- Abra o `Inspecionar`
- Nas abas, clique em `Application`
- No menu na lateral esquerda, clique em `LocalStorage`
- Clique no item que irá aparecer abaixo do `LocalStorage`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: valeu man! vou usa ra sua estrategia, esta funcionando